# Set a single word many times to bold

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple webpage project with 4 HTML5 pages, and 2 CSS stylesheets.

I need the specific word **"Arduino"**, that is repeated many times along all the pages, to be always showed in bold.

Is there any practical way to do it other than:

```
 <strong>Arduino</strong>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply way you can solve it.
  Just add this jQuery code:

[Live view](https://jsfiddle.net/ashikjs/wxgj473k/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // we define and invoke a function
    $("div").text(function () {
      $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/Arduino/g,'<b>Arduino</b>'));
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks this kinda worked. There are 2 "issues". Is there a way to get this to work without the div tags? Also, can I add another line with the arduino word in small caps?

Comment: Got it, changed the "div" to body and got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: sure just change the it div to body also you can add a small caps . :)
@TiraULTI  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to either always wrap the word in a tag (strong might make sense, but could be a span or whatever as well) so that it can be modified by css, *or* you would have to use javascript to parse the document and wrap it in a tag for you after the fact, and then, again, style that tag with css so that it is bold.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming strong is displayed as bold (if not use CSS):

Using jquery:

```
$("body").html(html.replace("Arduino", "<strong>Arduino</strong>")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am doing the following and it is not working.


 `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/arduino.js"></script>`

The arduino.js file looks like this.

`$(document).html(html.replace("Arduino", "<strong>Arduino</strong>")`

Comment: Put document.ready around the expression:
`$( document ).ready(function() {
   [EXPRESSION]
});` This will cause the expression to trigger once the site is fully loaded. Also you do not need jquery ui for this.

Comment: I am not being able to get it to work. I tried several ways, but I think this is the right one. Can you please correct me?
`$(document).ready(html.replace("Arduino", "<strong>Arduino</strong>"))`

Comment: stell it's not working. @TiraULTI Please take a look my answer you will be get excet code.

Comment: Well yeah you have to use body in the expression, not document. My mistake ;) Changed it

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript.

On document load, replace all strong words and change innerHTML of the article.

> var article = document.getElementById("content");
>
> article innerHTML = article innerHTML.
>   replace(/strongWord/g, "**strongWord**");

Answer (score 0):

You could set the font weight bold in CSS to whatever element in

i.e.:

```
<span id = "sometext"> Some Text </span>

CSS: 
#sometext{
font-weight:bold 
/* This can also be set to a px if you want a specific value i.e.: 20px */
}
```

OR

Use the `<strong>` tag to indicate if the text has significant meaning, or use the `<b>` tag if it does not.